# Win 2008 Server configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008

Let me preface my question by saying I'm a novice in regards to server configuration. It's been 12+ years since I've attempted this.

What we (our small office) are trying to achieve is to setup a Win 2008 server (located in a home) in a home network configuration (basic wireless router w/DHCP) that we (the office) can VPN to from our office.

I have installed the software, installed DHCP, removed DHCP from the router, set the scope for 100 IPs and am now looking for information as to where I go from here?

I believe I need to configure DNS and possibly set up static routes on the router for the home devices that need internet? Is there something I may be missing?

Also, would it be feasible to use the router's DHCP to assign IPs rather than having the server do it? If so, what would be the most direct way to accomplish this?

I appreciate any help in this matter.

Thanks

Comment: Read the FAQ - we don't do home stuff and the site's for professionals.

Comment: `where I go from here?` How the heck should we know?  You haven't told us what you want the server to do, or what you are having problems with.

Comment: If the data on this network is critical to the business, I strongly recommend you pay a pro to do this.  Internet security is not trivial and getting it wrong can be a disaster.

Answer (score 1):

No offense but go hire a professional. There are too many moving parts to try and explain in an answer here, let alone over the phone. There are plenty of people on SF that would be more than willing to come out for a certain price.  Check out http://careers.stackoverflow.com, it would be really easy to find someone to help you with this, even if its just in a consulting, instructional capacity.

The question is just too high level to really get much value in this medium.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way of configuring the Routers DHCP settings would be to use the routers webinterface.